# Term for sets in an affine space that are locally graphs of continuous functions

Tags: continuity, soft-question, terminology, geometric-topology, affine-geometry

I would like to make use of the following condition on a set $S$ in a finite-dimensional affine space $A$ (for example, a topological curve in a plane):

- each point of $S$ has a neighborhood $U$ in $A$ such that in some affine coordinate system, the intersection of $S$ with $U$ is given by an equation of the form
  $$
      x_n = f(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}),
    $$
  where $f$ is continuous.

Does there exist a term for such property, or at least for such curves in a plane? If not, is there some close property that has a name?

For curves, I might have called it something like *tame topological curve*.

Comment: The definition is different, but I suspect these are just manifolds.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, what do you mean by a *manifold*? There are parts of a plane homeomorphic to a line that do not have this property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve